# Typescript backticks syntax highlighting

Tags: javascript, angular, atom-editor

I am using angular 2 with typescript and when writing an inline template you use backticks.

but the content inside is not highlighted it stays the same color making it difficult to debug sometimes.

```
@Component({
    selector: "my-template-driven",
    template: `
      <h2>Sign-up Form</h2>
      <form (ngSubmit)="onSubmit(f)" #f="ngForm">
        <section>
          <label for="email">Email</label>
          <input type="email" id="email" ngControl="email" #email="ngForm">
          <span class="validation-error" required *ngIf="!email.valid">Not Valid</span>
        </section>
        <section>
          <label for="password">Password</label>
          <input type="password" id="password" ngControl="password" #password="ngForm">
          <span class="validation-error" required *ngIf="!password.valid">Not Valid</span>
        </section>
        <section>
          <label for="confirm-password">Confirm Password</label>
          <input type="confirm-password" id="confirm-password" ngControl="confirm-password" #confirmPassword = "ngForm">
          <span class="validation-error" required *ngIf="!confirmPassword.valid">Not Valid</span>
        </section>
        <button type="submit">Submit</button>
      </form>
    `

})
```

Is there a workaround this? Also is there any IDE that supports this?

Comment: I don't know about a plugin for atom. But `webstorm` does have this functionality. You can even jump to components, methods and properties from within a template

Comment: I'm using WebStorm 11.0.3, which has the functionality you're looking for.

Comment: https://www.jetbrains.com/help/phpstorm/2016.1/using-language-injections.html and https://blog.jetbrains.com/webstorm/tag/angular2/

Answer (score 1):

I have been informed by Nikolay Yakimov that as of v12 backticks syntax highlighting is no longer supported as `atom-typescript` does not have the resources to support their own grammar fork.

It also appears that `atom-typescript-zh-backticks` is no longer available either.

While I like some of the new features in v12 I feel that the loss of syntax formatting is too much of a cost.

`atom-typescript` still maintains a `legacy` branch, which has backticks syntax highlighting. To install that you will need to:

Uninstall `atom-typescript` from the package manager in atom. Then:

```
cd ~/.atom/packages
git clone -b legacy https://github.com/TypeStrong/atom-typescript.git
cd atom-typescript-legacy
npm install
```

Relaunch atom and check `atom-typescript` in the package manger. More than likely you will need to rebuild it and relaunch atom again.

Hopefully sometime soon someone will come up with a solution that doesn't rely on a legacy package. But until then this should work.

Answer (score 0):

There is an [open issue](https://github.com/TypeStrong/atom-typescript/issues/892) on the `atom-typescript` to add support for this, unfortunately, it doesn't look like the author has progressed it since March.

However, another developer has come up with a [fork of the `atom-typescript` repository](https://atom.io/packages/atom-typescript-zh-backticks) which does add support for syntax highlighting within backticks, you can install it from the command line by running:

```
apm install atom-typescript-zh-backticks
```

You can also find it from the `Install` tab within `Settings` (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>Comma</kbd>)

UPDATE: Now its part of the official atom-typescript package.

Comment: I know this is an old question, but I have v12 of atom-typescript and it does not seem to have this feature. Researching this issue it looks like the backticks formatting feature was added in v8. Has this feature since been removed? Also it looks like `atom-typescript-zh-backticks` no longer exists. It's still listed in Atom's list of packages, but the install file does not exist and it's ReadMe just has instruction on how to install `atom-typescript`.